# Aspect-ratio, using CSS and image doesn't render correcty?

Tags: css, image, aspect-ratio

Im just wondering if this is a browser rendering issue or incorrect css.
A nice way to scale a div in a defined aspect-ratio is, using a transparent image as a child element.
I have a small demo here. Under need this question.

But why doesn't it work nicely if I want a height of 100%.

I tested this in FF10,  Safari 5.1.2, IE8 and IE9. (only ie8 seems to render correctly...)

Hope somebody can explain the problem and maybe come up with a solution.

Regards,
Rik

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uk">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      html
    , body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: green;
    }

/*  AUTO WIDTH - doesnt render correct when scaling the browser window to a smaller size */
    .holder1 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        background: yellow;
        border-right: 1px solid red;
    }

    .holder1 .ratio {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }

/*  AUTO HEIGHT - works fine */
    .holder2 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        background: yellow;
        border-right: 1px solid red;
    }

    .holder2 .ratio {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="holder1">
        <img src="/images/empty_image.png" class="ratio" alt="Ratio image">
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `width` property does not make sense for `<span>` (since it has `display: inline`), so it just does nothing for .holder2.

Comment: @Alexander .hoder2 is not actually used in the demo (doesn't appear in markup)

Answer (score 1):

After view your question, I have some idea and suggest for your code:

1.Different between `width:auto` and `width:100%`, when you set auto for width, you leave the browser handle this width, with every different browser, they will handle `width:auto` follow their own rules. With `width:100%`, you force the browser must expand to have full width.That is what I think.
But for sure your div can expand 100% on every cross browsers, add css `min-width:100%`, it will do as you wish correctly.

2.About your CSS, I need you take a look at position:relative, this line of code have no sense, in this situation,

```
position:relative  = position:static
```

when you use position:relative, you must describe where is the position you wish your element relative to, add top or left to do it.

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Actually, your remark about `position:relative` is not entirely true. Although you're correct that it will be displayed in the same spot as if you didn't specify `position`, the element will behave differently with regards to float, z-index and so on. (I don't see that it matters here in the OP's example, but it may make a difference in his real website.)

Comment: Yup, I mentioned him this line of code have no sense in his example, but it will work if he has other child element that has it's style like `position:relative` or like you said.

Comment: @MrLister, can you tell me how z-index can make changes to position, maybe it will help me know more about css, thank you!

Comment: I meant that `position` can affect `z-index`, not the other way around. For instance, if you remove the `position:relative` from [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gwChV/) (or change it to `static`), you'll see that the `z-index` stops working.

Comment: @Tuong Thanks for having a look, I will double check the use of "auto" in different browsers. About your "position" tip, indeed in this example and doesn't need to be there. But when using elements inside this holder, that size the same way as there parent (the holder), I use position "absolute" on the childeren. That way I can scale a text area with an image in correct aspect-ratio :D